# Is it possible to capture NeoLoad script replay in Fiddler tool?

Tags: jmeter, fiddler, neoload

I am able to capture JMeter replay requests in Fiddler tool by launching JMeter via command line with proxy. I would like to know if NeoLoad replay requests can be captured in Fiddler as well?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you do this?  Neoload is a much more fully featured tool than Jmeter.   Any new Jmeter script you can develop you can just run inside of the same Neoload instance

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fiddler as a Proxy. You just have to configure Neoload to use your fiddler proxy to access your application.